# Multiple if-else conditions in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, if-statement

I have a sign-up view controller that contains multiple text fields to register the user.
I need to validate all the text fields such as **not empty**, **valid email**, **username**, **password** etc. and display the alert message for all different condition.

Now I following the approach as:

```
if (condition) {
    if (condition) {
        if (condition) {
        } else {
            [alert show];
        }
    } else {
        [alert show];
    }
} else {
    [alert show];
}
```

I know this is not the best approach. So guys please suggest an appropriate way to do that task.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Multiple If else Condition

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];

NSString *mobileRegex = @"[0-9]{6,14}$";
NSPredicate *mobileTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", mobileRegex]


if  (txtName.text.length == 0)
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please Enter Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}
else if  (txtMobile.text.length == 0)
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please Enter Mobile Number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}
else if ([mobileTest evaluateWithObject:txtMobile.text] == NO)
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please Enter valid Mobile Number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}
else if  (txtMobile.text.length < 10)
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please Enter valid Phone Number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}
else if  (txtMobile.text.length > 10)
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please Enter valid Phone Number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}
else if  (txtEmail.text.length == 0)
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please Enter Email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}
else if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:txtEmail.text] == NO)
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please Enter valid Email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}
else
{
 //success Code
}
```

Comment: else use IBOUTLETCollection bro,

Comment: @Anbu How would I use Outlet collection for do that?

Comment: @iDev750 - surely you can use

Comment: @iDev750 - actually understand purpose I added this , we can csutomize this

Answer (score 2):

Here `isAllFieldsAreValid()` will validate all the fields you can add all the validation here.

`showAlert` is a method to show alert about error.

`allTrim()` is a macro that will trim whitespace.

```
- (BOOL)isAllFieldsAreValid {

    //here only empty string is checked you can add other if-else to validate email, phno, etc.

    if ([allTrim(self.txtFname.text) isEqualToString:@""]) {

        [self showAlert:@"Please enter first name."];
        return false;

    } else if ([allTrim(self.txtLname.text) isEqualToString:@""]) {

        [self showAlert:@"Please enter last name."];
        return false;

    } else if ([allTrim(self.txtEmail_SignUp.text) isEqualToString:@""]) {

        [self showAlert:@"Please enter email id."];
        return false;

    } else if ([allTrim(self.txtPassword_SignUp.text) isEqualToString:@""]) {

        [self showAlert:@"Please enter password."];
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

You can call this on button click and upon true and false you can take action.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTappedInLoginView:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ([self isAllFieldsAreValid]) {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Richard. I think this is much better way to check multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
if (firstnametf.text.length==0 || lastnametf.text.length==0 || emailtf.text.length==0 || myimageView.image == nil || commenttf.text.length==0 || [commenttf.text isEqualToString:@"Comment"])

            {
                [self validatetextfield];

            }
        else if (![emailtf.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {

             NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
             NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
                //Valid email address
             if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailtf.text] == YES)
                {
                      //All conditions are checked, you will set the function
                }
                else if () 
                {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test!" message:@"Please Enter Valid Email Address. \nex. fdsjfkd@mail.com" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                }

         }
}
```

Method:

```
-(void) validatetextfield
{
    if (firstnametf.text.length==0) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Firstname Field Empty!" message:@"Please Enter the Valid Details" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [firstnametf becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (lastnametf.text.length==0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Lastname Field Empty!" message:@"Please Enter the Valid Details" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [lastnametf becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (emailtf.text.length==0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email Field Empty!" message:@"Please Enter the Valid Details" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [emailtf becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if(commenttf.text.length==0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Comment Field Empty!" message:@"Please Enter the Valid Details" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [commenttf becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if ([commenttf.text isEqualToString:@"Comment"])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Comment Field Empty!" message:@"Please Enter the Valid Details" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [commenttf becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (myimageView.image == nil)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Image not Upload!" message:@"Please Upload Image" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
```

Change the Alert condition, hope its helpful

Comment: Why are you using [tf becomeFirstResponder] in every if block? I think there is no need to add this line.

Comment: becomeFirstResponder is used to when the alert show click ok automatically edit the particular `UITextfield` and keyboard thats the reason to used, its not necessary but my source need, check it

Comment: But I hope keyboard automatically appears on active text field after click ok on alert if you don't resign the keyboard before showing the alert.